# Lerna run only on changed packages

Tags: lerna, monorepo

We have mono repo set up which holds 13 packages. It's very unlikely that we change all of them at any given release. I am trying to find a way to run `lerna run ....` only on `changed` packages. I did try with `--since master`, looks it does not work on master branch. What is the best way I can achieve this? I am thinking of writing a scripts which reads from `lerna changed` and run those commands.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what and when (eg precommit) you are trying to run, in general, when on `master`, simple `lerna run test --since` should do it. There was a [gh issue](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2211#issuecomment-592703853).

Also, you can look at `lint-staged` [package](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged) that could help you. It allows us to run commands against *staged* files. So if you only changed stuff in `packageA` - linting, prettiering or running tests inside `lint-staged` will save you time.